# onStart() call startService() sometimes causes exception in Android O

Tags: android, android-service

Our app is targeting Android O.

After reading [Background Service Limitation](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background#services), I have come to notice that it is safe for a **foreground app** to launch services. Therefore in our app we called `startService()` in our Fragment's `onStart()` method. We think this is ok because in [this document](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onStart()) it says when onStart is called, fragment is visible to the user and when it is visible, it means this app is a foreground app.

But sometimes, and I must admit it happens pretty rare, we still receive the following exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent {
>   act=ACTION_DEACTIVATE cmp=com.adyxe.sync/.ClientService }: app is
>   in background uid UidRecord{db2a697 u0a19 LAST bg:+7m30s540ms idle
>   change:cached procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}

Why is this happening? Is it safer to call startService() in `onResume()` just to be more sure that the app is now a foreground app?

Comment: your service extends Service/IntentService or JobIntentService?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You might have found a bug in Android :)

Regardless, You should use a `JobIntentService` and enqueue it.

This way **the system will run your service** when the app is considered in the foreground and you will not see the error. In pre-Oreo versions the service should run immediately regardless of the app foreground state.

Here is an example:

```
public class ExampleJobIntentService extends JobIntentService {
  static final int JOB_ID = 1000;

  static void enqueueWork(Context context, Intent work) {
    enqueueWork(context, ExampleJobIntentService.class, JOB_ID, work);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Some initializations...
  }

  @Override
  protected void onHandleWork(Intent work) {
    // Do your stuff...
  }

  @Override
  public boolean onStopCurrentWork() {
    // return true to reschedule this service if your work failed.
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then you enqueue it like this:

```
// The intent is the one that will be received here: onHandleWork(Intent work)
ExampleJobIntentService.enqueueWork(context, intent);
```

Register it in the `Manifest` like this:

```
<service
     android:name=".ExampleJobIntentService"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
```

If you plan on running the service in the background as well you should add the `WAKE_LOCK` permission in the `Manifest` for **pre-Oreo** versions:

```
<uses-permission android:name=”android.permission.WAKE_LOCK” />
```

Comment: JobIntentService can't be used to replace foreground services, such as ones which display an ongoing notification. eg a music player service